# netbeans 8 phpdoc not working

Tags: php, netbeans-8, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I have set my phpdoc as follows

[image]

When I try to generate php documentor then its showing following error

> ERROR: Unknown command-line option "--ansi" encountered, use phpdoc -h for help

what i am doing wrong here. I have also set php path in "General" tab as `C:\xampp\php\php.exe`

Windows 7 & XAMPP, PHP 5.6